# RSA Modulus doesn't match the primes

Tags: encryption, rsa, key-derivation, prime-numbers

I generated a 2048-bit RSA key with ssh-keygen. When running:

```
openssl rsa -in key -noout -text
```

The result is:

```
Private-Key: (2048 bit)
modulus:
    00:cb:df:46:64:71:ec:0e:f2:40:d2:65:da:6f:17:
    80:70:ad:30:31:eb:c4:a1:ff:f5:ec:d3:c7:f1:b1:
    af:bc:e9:98:56:df:ee:d6:c3:d0:1c:1b:67:9a:a8:
    ac:46:32:22:f0:97:10:26:f7:ad:ab:da:8a:4f:3f:
    8e:1a:ac:2d:c6:5e:e8:b6:70:1e:4e:15:b7:ea:e4:
    23:6e:29:59:e3:7d:c7:15:74:60:86:16:d1:92:4c:
    cc:bb:22:15:ae:2c:22:01:5b:89:68:89:e1:aa:53:
    32:5d:7f:26:de:97:ea:db:da:38:56:0a:2b:b3:0d:
    c7:dd:1a:c4:63:cf:c5:90:78:f6:0b:26:21:f0:29:
    02:73:cd:0c:5d:84:e4:9c:15:e8:d7:98:e3:02:15:
    4d:62:a7:14:14:07:05:4e:28:8a:ca:48:92:23:d8:
    4a:f1:a7:88:f8:9a:4f:d0:27:73:3a:62:fc:7d:9d:
    aa:ba:a1:5b:8e:ea:79:04:de:88:b7:31:89:44:d7:
    15:03:8b:64:6d:20:e4:9b:f5:33:88:49:8c:7b:8e:
    f6:d0:97:83:1c:2c:8a:70:a1:65:ab:ac:b9:76:d6:
    77:f9:7b:a0:c8:1d:56:d6:74:d6:4f:0a:5f:dc:e2:
    87:fc:dd:e7:9b:cb:77:9e:f7:12:d7:44:a3:14:f6:
    5f:5f
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    00:92:f0:3a:e8:fc:5e:fa:2a:ca:63:9a:7b:84:24:
    39:33:7c:ef:c6:9b:3a:5e:d4:7f:e8:90:7f:84:88:
    df:b3:d5:dd:31:88:36:b9:5d:ea:69:c7:aa:b5:82:
    aa:9f:f1:54:d3:78:dd:70:68:85:28:de:db:5e:e0:
    dc:c8:06:9e:fb:61:be:72:77:7e:b0:22:e1:2b:10:
    01:25:4d:f2:76:8f:59:e4:f1:ba:fc:0a:08:44:5c:
    cc:16:78:2b:8e:1c:4a:ea:15:92:84:e1:13:df:d2:
    14:f3:e4:48:1c:98:fb:f2:37:66:f1:44:65:58:a9:
    2f:0b:02:56:d7:e5:91:6c:5d:28:97:0d:b0:22:e0:
    6b:71:3e:79:15:67:bb:ca:b8:f1:60:4c:70:df:16:
    93:1b:3b:2c:ba:c1:7d:f8:1a:fc:21:af:fe:1a:69:
    f3:4a:3a:41:a2:9b:a7:8f:44:56:0f:35:d5:81:db:
    f8:f0:89:6b:76:f2:56:bf:f2:52:7a:2b:bd:78:ba:
    d5:fa:8a:f8:1f:27:16:61:ff:1b:cc:0c:3e:75:01:
    07:6e:e0:ac:62:4f:86:0d:51:b6:cf:a9:e7:4d:1a:
    84:ef:61:60:01:ff:31:57:e5:f8:2c:60:9a:cd:3a:
    e9:cf:27:96:be:5f:22:d4:12:95:fd:60:3c:33:1d:
    46:d1
prime1:
    00:e3:ae:54:73:03:0c:3d:2d:52:68:d6:f2:d1:d8:
    2e:7e:0b:14:9f:f5:ae:a3:3d:bf:4a:40:2b:fe:18:
    99:4d:23:ab:af:53:1d:b0:e3:27:e9:b4:63:af:54:
    04:dc:3c:bd:dc:c4:fb:1f:fe:c8:03:38:6f:7f:00:
    5e:80:05:2a:19:52:be:af:1b:8a:96:f1:4d:f5:32:
    32:5f:b0:2d:89:04:f0:c1:4a:b1:3b:b5:e0:96:a0:
    af:b1:f4:0f:b8:38:35:f3:55:d9:78:40:7e:7e:ba:
    3b:04:1b:ff:c7:9c:6f:77:b9:38:fa:e9:65:d0:09:
    34:34:da:9f:06:78:37:32:95
prime2:
    00:d8:90:ad:b6:d0:94:eb:f2:1b:7d:18:7e:cf:fe:
    29:48:02:c2:4f:1f:b7:e4:47:9d:cc:df:51:55:2d:
    4d:23:f0:93:8b:25:42:fe:a4:0a:57:48:9c:d0:7f:
    33:2b:10:5e:e6:68:c5:dc:53:c8:0e:77:51:a3:14:
    b5:a0:23:f1:87:4c:75:0e:c6:48:99:ec:3f:d4:ef:
    51:8c:ce:d2:3c:c8:2b:e5:2e:d3:9e:6b:f9:f3:d3:
    b1:50:46:59:bd:66:1f:04:f4:72:43:87:c7:32:de:
    69:fe:ea:19:e3:fb:b1:23:2a:d8:29:73:ec:04:54:
    45:be:c7:e6:56:05:b1:ac:c3
exponent1:
    7a:5d:38:f9:cf:0b:86:dd:92:ca:d1:ab:12:e8:92:
    a4:1f:24:68:8b:cb:dd:e3:d3:a8:fe:30:26:91:e5:
    e2:35:67:92:04:a3:92:6b:a3:09:d1:6f:39:cd:78:
    07:3d:85:f4:de:d0:f0:73:27:df:c3:36:f9:14:a3:
    b5:3e:11:50:26:ce:60:a1:f6:ac:04:e8:16:fd:71:
    61:47:f8:51:09:9c:b2:e5:87:b7:45:9a:7c:99:c3:
    93:6a:4e:00:7e:05:50:d0:34:de:92:1a:e9:d5:00:
    de:c6:85:83:2c:2a:24:38:21:cd:88:1e:b5:de:1c:
    76:c3:80:70:23:af:d6:b9
exponent2:
    00:cc:20:8a:ec:cf:6c:1f:7d:c4:35:44:7a:7b:78:
    58:d6:dc:6a:e4:83:c4:24:72:f0:a5:64:35:58:70:
    eb:ce:1d:7c:24:e2:c9:64:15:a0:fd:a6:9e:d0:d3:
    a4:9a:49:c2:f9:b0:f6:16:f8:0d:90:bd:1d:00:f7:
    8b:3e:d7:c2:58:42:53:ef:ca:2c:32:91:81:95:26:
    c2:9a:53:73:cd:00:ec:87:08:7d:45:4d:07:7b:b1:
    24:e7:c2:77:e1:d3:39:17:c5:85:52:6b:cf:f1:fd:
    bc:b1:1f:5d:aa:0b:da:6a:88:7e:d9:8b:bf:82:51:
    20:b0:73:e1:83:61:b8:98:5b
coefficient:
    4c:a7:10:44:f1:a8:b2:5e:10:cc:ac:22:4f:8b:49:
    15:00:b3:a9:11:16:10:19:1c:8e:28:be:e7:e2:d7:
    48:23:a3:c6:8e:9b:d3:41:eb:11:64:9f:0a:17:c4:
    ba:c3:1f:4e:af:77:cb:38:be:96:75:a3:32:1c:a5:
    c4:53:fd:5d:80:28:b3:95:c8:74:f5:77:d4:8b:7a:
    7d:6f:4b:ba:f0:c6:65:03:54:71:70:84:02:b8:f3:
    df:e0:d2:64:14:78:da:2e:72:80:e4:14:7c:8e:f5:
    3a:83:ee:72:bb:99:98:9c:63:31:d3:c1:6f:e5:73:
    85:55:94:27:3c:31:16:8e
```

However the prime numbers

```
0xd890adb6d094ebf21b7d187ecffe294802c24f1fb7e4479dccdf51552d4d23f0938b2542fea40a57489cd07f332b105ee668c5dc53c80e7751a314b5a023f1874c750ec64899ec3fd4ef518cced23cc82be52ed39e6bf9f3d3b1504659bd661f04f4724387c732de69feea19e3fbb1232ad82973ec045445bec7e65605b1acc3 * 0x00e3ae5473030c3d2d5268d6f2d1d82e7e0b149ff5aea33dbf4a402bfe18994d23abaf531db0e327e9b463af5404dc3cbddcc4fb1ffec803386f7f005e80052a1952beaf1b8a96f14df532325fb02d8904f0c14ab13bb5e096a0afb1f40fb83835f355d978407e7eba3b041bffc79c6f77b938fae965d0093434da9f0678373295
```

don't multiply to get the modulus value

```
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
```

But instead multiply to get:

```
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
```

I'm trying to figure out why this would be, considering that the modulus is supposed to be the product of both primes.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the correct site, but, you should also include how did you multiply the primes.

Comment: I assumed it would have a better chance of being answered in here than anywhere else due to the nature of cryptography. As for how it was multiplied, it was just done in Python (which supports big integers such as these). I've also multiplied it in an online big number calculator just to check and the same value is output.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=openssl+rsa

Comment: The values of publicExponent, prime1, prime2, exponent1, exponent2, coefficient are consistent. But the values of modulus and privateExponent are not consistent with the rest; nor are they mutually consistent for the stated publicExponent. How that happened is off-topic.